# Failure to resolve System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat when using Npgsql with Mono

Tags: c#, macos, mono, npgsql

I'm trying to use Npgsql in a mono app (built for Mac in Xamarin Studio).  I was previously using Npgsql 2.x, and that worked OK for me, though gave us cryptic errors related to SSL on another machine.  So yesterday I upgraded to the latest (3.0.5) version of Npgsql, but now when I try to build, I get an error:

> error MM2002: Failed to resolve
>   "System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat::get_EccPublicBlob()"
>   reference from "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

I [posted](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/176996) about this on the Xamarin forums, and was told "Poking around mono, mcs/class/System.Core/System.Security.Cryptography/CngKeyBlobFormat.cs exists but is not included in any build currently."

I'm still relatively new to mono, and don't know how to proceed from here.  What do I need to do to use Npgsql in my mono Mac app?

Answer (score 0):

> "Poking around mono, mcs/class/System.Core/System.Security.Cryptography/CngKeyBlobFormat.cs exists but is not included in any build currently."

It means that the class is not included in [this file](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/common_System.Core.dll.sources).

Now, given that this class is in [Microsoft's sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/), you should create a pull request that links to [that class](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/CngKeyBlobFormat.cs) (via relative path, like other classes are linked already), and remove [the old Mono implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Security.Cryptography/CngKeyBlobFormat.cs).

NOTE: After you create your pull request (which is easy enough), you will be notified by a Jenkins bot if your change breaks the build or not. If it breaks it, most probably it will be because this class depends on some other one (then, to fix it, just add a new entry in the .sources file; keep doing this until it passes).

**UPDATE**: Given that you seemed unwilling to contribute to fix the problem yourself, I went ahead and fixed it myself proposing [this pull request](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/2613), which has been merged today. This means that Mono 4.3 (or 4.4) will contain the fix.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do most of that.  But let me see if I understand anything: (1) Npgsql now requires this file; (2) there is no Mono implementation of this file; (3) Npgsql is therefore not compatible with Mono, unless (4) each user hacks together their own build of Mono by pulling from Microsoft's source?  Is this all correct?

Comment: no, I'm suggesting you do a pull request to Mono so you can fix Mono for yourself and for all the people that may have this problem in the future

Comment: That's surprising.  I didn't think Mono was allowed to just include Microsoft source code.  But clearly I was mistaken.

Comment: FWIW, the "real" problem here (or at the very least, another way to look at it) appears to be that the Xamarin linker needs to resolve every type referenced anywhere by the source, whereas apparently the "standard" (whatever that means) mono linker on most platforms is content with not resolving some things, and failing at runtime.  But the use of this type is already in an if-block which prevents it from ever being called on XamMac, so the authors of Npgsql (who I guess use a more permissive linker) believed it wasn't a problem.

Comment: All that said, if this type appears in the future Mono builds, then I guess that probably will solve it.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Mono has been including Microsoft source code (and deleting their code) since Microsoft published .NET under the MIT license.